# Java can't create MIME Header?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

OK, I'm using a Java agent to loop through and convert an number of Base64 strings to the images they represent. I'm having trouble setting the headerVal. Below is the block of code. Logging shows I'm getting the body as it is already a MIMEEntity, but even thought I create the header, (twice) it's not their either time - so both lines where I say the header is null print. I finally get a null pointer exception on the header.setHeaderVal("image/png") line. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here?

Cheers, 
Brian

```
MIMEEntity body;                         
if(doc.hasItem("body")){ 
        System.out.println("has MIME body"); 
        body = doc.getMIMEEntity("body"); 
} else { 
        System.out.println("before create MIME body"); 
        body = doc.createMIMEEntity(); 
} 
if(body == null){ 
        body = doc.createMIMEEntity(); 
        System.out.println("body was null"); 
} 
System.out.println("after body item"); 
allObjects.addElement(body); 

if (body == null){ 
        System.out.println("hmm, body is null"); 
} 

System.out.println("before header"); 
//MIMEHeader header = null; 
MIMEHeader header = body.createHeader("Content-Type"); 
System.out.println("after header"); 
if(header == null ){ 
        System.out.println("header was null???"); 
        header = body.createHeader("Content-Type"); 
        System.out.println("after header null create"); 
} 
allObjects.addElement(header); 
if(header == null ){ 
        System.out.println("header was null AGAIN???"); 
        header = body.createHeader("Content-Type"); 
        System.out.println("after header null create AGAIN"); 
} 
System.out.println("after header add object"); 
header.setHeaderVal("image/png");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you missing the `session.setConvertMIME(false)`?

Here's parts from an example from the Designer help:

```
  // Do not convert MIME to rich text
  session.setConvertMIME(false);
  Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
  Document doc = db.createDocument();
  // Create parent entity
  doc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
  MIMEEntity body = doc.createMIMEEntity();
  MIMEHeader header = body.createHeader("Content-Type");
  header.setHeaderVal("multipart/mixed");
```

Comment: It seems to have been a combination of the MIME conversion (which was in earlier versions, but I've been doing a lot of work) and that various attempts on the same document had a _lot_ of $FILE fields. Thank Per, I owe you a drink at LotusSphere.

Comment: You're welcome, Brian. Looking forward to meet you (and have a drink) :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can find beyond adding the aforementioned setConvertMime method is that the documentation states for the `createHeader` method:

> This method returns Nothing if creation of the header exceeds a known
>   limit for headers of the same name.

I suppose that might occur if you've set the Content-Type previously in code?